# 1999 mazda 626 v6 Lx, 140k miles engine wanting to stall @ stops

Tags: mazda, mazda-626

Just had a local shop do a timing belt/water pump. Something feels off, now she wants to idle down to almost a  stall when I come to a stop.
Suggestions?

Comment: I would start with getting an intake tract cleaning (like a Seafoam treatment) and then get the IAC valve recalibrated (if possible).